# Referencing a method from a class which is nested

Tags: java

I'm a JAVA beginner. 
I am trying to create a java phonebook which as three main classes

- `Contacts.java`
- `Phonebook.java`
- `Showphonebook.java`

`Contacts` has two variables that are non-static, `name` and `phone`, which hold name and phone numbers of a person.

Then `Phonebook` is a class which holds the `Phonebook` objects and has a variable `owner` which is a string. So basically, the `Phonebook` object holds a owner and makes references to `Contacts` object to add contacts to it.

Then the final class `Showphonebook` is the class that makes a new `Phonebook` with owner and adds contacts to it.

Here is my code for above:

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Contact(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + phone;
    }
}
```

**Phonebook.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Phonebook
{
    private String owner;
    public ArrayList<Contact> contacts =  new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public Phonebook(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void addContact(Contact name) {
        contacts.add(name);
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(owner + "'s phonebook");
        for (Contact name : contacts) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    /*public String findContactByName(String contactToSearch) {
        for (Contact name : contacts) {
            if (this.getName().equals(contactToSearch)) {

            }
        }
    }*/

}
```

**ShowPhonebook.java**

```
public class ShowPhonebook
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phonebook phonebook1 = new Phonebook("Sam Johnson");
        phonebook1.addContact(new Contact("Kelly Wong", "(02) 12345678"));
        phonebook1.addContact(new Contact("Richard Jackson", "(02) 87654321"));
        phonebook1.show();
    }
}
```

I wanted to make a method in Phonebook.java which can SEARCH the phonebook to see if a contact exists , else return null.

How can I do this? I was thinking if I will use `getName()` method in `Contact` to pull out the NAME of each contact in the contacts `ArrayList` and compare it to the `contactToSearch` variable, but since `getName()` is non-static, how do I do it? I am confused because `Contact` holds the `getName`, but to reference that, I need an object, but my only object `phonebook1` is in `ShowPhonebook` class, which I feel has to go through two classes to get there. Not sure how to do it.

Looking for guidance here!

Comment: ```if (this.getName().equals(contactToSearch)) {``` => ```this``` has no ```.getName()```. You want to do that on the ```name``` variable. This is what you use the foreach for.

Comment: *"[...] if there exists a person who I search, else return null."*, so what is it supposed to return when found? Just return a boolean and let it be true or false depending on the existence.

Comment: FYI: Please consider putting some time into researching what *static* is. You seem to not realy understand it.

Comment: My suggestion: I believe the class Showphonebook is not needed yet. The searching capacity can be put directly into Phonebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to stack overflow!

Now I'm assuming you are new to java hence confused about how references and `this` work in java. To get what you are asking, I would suggest following modification in the commented method-

```
public String findContactByName(String contactToSearch) {
    for (Contact contact : this.contacts) { // changed "name" to "contact"; variable name should be aptly chosen
        if (contact.getName().equals(contactToSearch)) {
            // TODO: do your thing with "contact" variable
        }
    }
}
```

`this` refers to the current instance of the class. In your case, `this` will refer to the `phonebook1` instance.